# Python script for constructing a WHERE clause from user input

Tags: arcgis-10.0, python, sql

I'm trying to construct a where clause from user input that will eventually be passed through as a SQL statement in the select tool or the select by attributes tool. I've started a script thats been adapted from some previous posts, however, I still don't have it correct. the way its currently written the resulting SQL statement will look something like:

"123" = 'ABC' OR 'DEF'

I need the resulting statement to look more like

"\123\" = 'ABC' OR "\123\"='DEF'

Important: the values (i.e. ABC DEF) will be user inputs and the number of values entered as arguments may vary from user to user. My current script is below

```
 def whereClause(table, field, values):
    """Takes a semicolon-delimited list of values and constructs a SQL WHERE
    clause to select those values within a given field and table."""

    # Add field delimiters
    fieldDelimited = arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(arcpy.Describe(table).path, field)

    # Split multivalue at semicolons and strip quotes
    valueList = [value[1:-1]
        if (value.startswith("'") and value.endswith("'"))
        else value for value in values.split(';')]

    # Determine field type
    fieldType = arcpy.ListFields(table, field)[0].type

    # Add single-quotes for string field values
    if str(fieldType) == 'String':
        valueList = ["'%s'" % value for value in valueList]

    # Format WHERE clause in the form of an IN statement
    whereClause = "%s = %s" % (fieldDelimited, 'OR' .join(valueList))
    return whereClause

def outName(input,post="Out",fileExtension="shp"):
    """Returns output name."""
    outName=os.path.basename(input).split(".")[0]+post+"."+fileExtension
    return outName

# Create SQL Statement
InputFC = arcpy.GetParametersAsText(0)
outputFC=outName(InputFC,"_Select")
Field ="CO_NAME"
Values = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1) #user input
SQL=whereClause(InputFC,Field,Values)  
print SQL
```

Comment: Can you post the error message you are getting, it will help with debugging the script.

Comment: Also, an example input dataset would be handy.

Comment: Does it always need to have the slashes like in "\123\"?

Comment: Some more test values would be nice, too.

Comment: @R.K. yes, according to formatting rules in ArcGIS 10.0 the field  from which the attributes are being selected needs to follow this format. As far as supplying test dat, I'm new to this forum - how do i do that?

Comment: Just upload the file somewhere and post the link to the file in your question.

Comment: Can also add what your input test values are? It's kinda hard to just guess.

Answer (score 3):

Making lots of assumptions here. Here's my edits.

```
 def whereClause(table, field, values):
    """Takes a semicolon-delimited list of values and constructs a SQL WHERE
    clause to select those values within a given field and table."""

    # Add field delimiters
    fieldDelimited = arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(arcpy.Describe(table).path, field)

    #adds the slashes
    fieldDelimited = '"\\%s\\"' % (fieldDelimited[1:-1])

    # Split multivalue at semicolons and strip quotes
    valueList = [value[1:-1]
        if (value.startswith("'") and value.endswith("'"))
        else value for value in values.split(';')]

    # Determine field type
    fieldType = arcpy.ListFields(table, field)[0].type

    # Add single-quotes for string field values
    if str(fieldType) == 'String':
        valueList = ["'%s'" % value for value in valueList]

    # Format WHERE clause in the form of an IN statement
    whereClause = ''
    for value in valueList:
        if whereClause == '':
            whereClause = "%s = %s" % (fieldDelimited, value)
            continue 
        else:
            prevClause = str(whereClause)
            whereClause = "%s = %s" % (fieldDelimited, value)
            whereClause = "%s OR %s" %  (prevClause, whereClause)
    return whereClause

def outName(input,post="Out",fileExtension="shp"):
    """Returns output name."""
    outName=os.path.basename(input).split(".")[0]+post+"."+fileExtension
    return outName

# Create SQL Statement
InputFC = arcpy.GetParametersAsText(0)
outputFC=outName(InputFC,"_Select")
Field ="CO_NAME"
Values = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1) #user input
SQL=whereClause(InputFC,Field,Values)  
print SQL
```

Do try it on your test data and see if it works.

Comment: @sgrieve if I try and run the current script through the select by attribute tool the error message reads: "ExecuteError: ERROR 000210: Cannot create output CountyBoundary_Select.shp" This makes sense since the format of the SQL statement is incorrect (as noted in my orginal post)

Comment: thank you for working on this, unfortunately, it doesn't work. I get the following error message: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.0\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 326, in RunScript
    exec codeObject in __main__.__dict__
  File "C:\GIS540_Project\sql_RKedits.py", line 44, in <module>
    SQL=whereClause(InputFC,Field,Values)
  File "C:\GIS540_Project\sql_RKedits.py", line 25, in whereClause
    if whereClause == "":
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'whereClause' referenced before assignment

Comment: Fixed. Can you try it again? Forgot to initialize whereClause.

Comment: @ R.K. - it now runs without an error but basically gives me back the same situation as my original post : "\CO_NAME\" = '123:456'

Comment: Can you tell me what the value of valueList in this case is?

Comment: You said that in your original post the value is `"123" = 'ABC' OR 'DEF'`. So which one is it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6054/discussion-between-r-k-and-rralbritton)

Comment: @ R.K. - sorry. had to leave for job #2 after I posted. To answer your question, "123" = 'ABC' OR 'DEF' "which is it?' = both. If the ultimate goal is to select attributes ABC and DEF from field 123 then the correct SQL statement form for ArcGIS should read "123" = 'ABC' OR "123" = 'DEF'. This would select out both ABC and DEF